# Selecting Rows in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm starting to learn about CSS grid. However, i try to research on how to select the 2 rows and span it to the end if I have 12 rows and 12 columns. In that rows ill be going to put a navigation link.

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #5DADE2;
  height: 100%;
}

.mainbox {
  display: grid;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

header {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <header>
    <nav><a href="#">Home</a></nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: `grid-row: 2 / -1;` since you want row not column?

Comment: I recommend these video tutorials https://gridbyexample.com/video/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.mainbox {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

header {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;  /* new; span across rows 1 & 2 */
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #5DADE2;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <header>
    <nav><a href="#">Home</a></nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was a great help